# How do I remove the heroku cloud application platform repository?

Tags: software-sources, software-uninstall, heroku

I am having problem with heroku cloud platform. I am having problem with `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

In this directory the heroku file have been saved. I installed it via terminal using `sudo apt-get install heroku`.

Comment: What is the problem you facing? Give some details. What you did etc. Please post your question with sufficient details. Otherwise no one can answer regardless of how many time you ask. Dup: http://askubuntu.com/questions/134331/i-installed-ubuntu-12-04-on-my-acer-netbook-and-having-problem-when-i-installed

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed it via `apt-get`, it should be removed by

`sudo apt-get --purge remove heroku`

Post if any error comes or if its still not removed.

Comment: i am getting an error "unable to locate package heroku"...what should i do??

Comment: that means the package has been removed already.What are the problems you are faceing? There is one file inside that direcotory,does that bother you? It is harmless to have a list file inside the directory you mentioned. However run `gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list `  and delete the line with heraku source. then run `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: E: malformed line 1 in source list/etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list

this line is poping in terminal...

Comment: E:Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list (dist) this is the main and serious error for my system...please help.. due to this problem i am uable to load the new packages....please help..

Comment: i have done with that problem but not by your way because as per your command i was getting same error. i tried another one command run sudo rm etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list